# Scala- How do I determine if an object is thread-safe?

Tags: scala, concurrency

```
object GetDetails{
  def apply(outStream: java.io.Writer, someObject: SomeClass){
    outStream.write(someObject.detail1) //detail1 is string
    outStream.write(someObject.detail2) //detail2 is also string
    outStream.flush()
  }
}
```

If this implementation is not thread-safe how do I make it thread-safe?

This function is going to be called simultaneously with different inputs.

Comment: As long as inputs are different (and not connected to the same stream underneath), you are fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to think about is how the "state" of your application might change when two different threads call the same function, or interact with the same object. In this case, your "state" might be "what's been written to `outStream`".

Consider the following scenario:

```
Thread 1                                 Thread 2
--------------------                     -------------------------------
GetDetails(outStream, object1)
                                         GetDetails(outStream, object2)
  outStream.write(object1.detail1)
                                           outStream.write(object2.detail1)
  outStream.write(object1.detail2)
                                           outStream.write(object2.detail2)
                                           outStream.flush()
  outStream.flush()
```

Two separate threads both call `GetDetails`, sharing the same `outStream`. This is a potential concurrency problem, as the data that gets written to `outStream` is not guaranteed to be in any particular order. You might get `[object1.detail1, object2.detail1, object1.detail2, object2.detail2]`, or  `[object2.detail1, object1.detail1, object1.detail2, object2.detail2]`, and so on.

`GetDetails.apply` does not change any of `GetDetails`'s state, but it does change the state of the `Writer` that you pass; in order to ensure thread-safety you must take efforts to avoid using the same Writer at the same time (i.e. the scenario above).

As a counter-point, here's a pretty thread-**un**safe method:

```
object NotThreadSafe {
  // mutable state
  private var currentPrefix = ""

  def countUp(prefix: String) = {
    // red flag: changing mutable state, then referring to it
    currentPrefix = prefix
    for(i <- 1 to 5) println(s"$currentPrefix $i")
  }
}
```

If thread 1 calls `NotThreadSafe.countUp("hello")` and thread 2 calls `NotThreadSafe.countUp("goodbye")`, the output will depend on which `currentPrefix = prefix` happens last.

You could end up with

> hello 1
>   hello 2
>   goodbye 3 // should have been hello 3, but currentPrefix got changed
>   goodbye 1
>   goodbye 4 // should have been hello 4
>   goodbye 5 // should have been hello 5
>   goodbye 2
>   goodbye 3
>   goodbye 4
>   goodbye 5

or one of many other permutations.

This is one reason why Scala tends to prefer "immutability" and "statelessness", because those are tools that simply don't need to worry about this kind of issue.

If you do find yourself forced to deal with mutable state, often the simplest way to ensure thread safety is to ensure your method can only be called once at a time, i.e. by using `synchronized`. At a finer-grained level, you want to ensure that a specific sequence of steps is not interleaved with another copy of that sequence on another thread (e.g. the GetDetails scenario I described at the beginning).

You could also look into [semaphores](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) but that's beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Would getting rid of streams and having the function return a List[String] guarantee thread safety?

Comment: @AnIllusion If your `getDetails` method does not affect any state outside of its own local vals/vars, then yes. If all you are doing is building a `List` to be returned, then yes, because you aren't affecting any other state.